# can i make changes to swing component property at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

When you make a change to a JSP page in Eclipse while the web server is running, then recompile it, the changes show up in a browser on the next page reload.

Can i do something similar with Swing components in a Java application? Suppose I have a JFrame containing a JLabel with the text `"fname"`. I'd like to be able to change that to `"first name"` and have the text of the JLabel in the running application immediately change without having to quit and restart the application. That doesn't work when I try it. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for help in advance.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pack3;


/**
 *
 * @author Love Poet
 */
public class ChangeAtRuntime extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ChangeAtRuntime
     */
    public ChangeAtRuntime() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Name");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(151, 151, 151)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(204, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(116, 116, 116)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(162, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChangeAtRuntime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChangeAtRuntime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChangeAtRuntime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChangeAtRuntime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ChangeAtRuntime().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You can't do anything without paragraphs

Comment: How about formatting your question so that it can be easily read by humans

Comment: actually sir i am new to the stackowerflow and i dont now any thing like this

Comment: Ah sorry you are not an English speaker?

Comment: yes i am from india so i can speak english a little

Answer (score 1):

If you call the `setText()` method on your JLabel instance at runtime, it should update the text that is displayed.  Just call `setText()` from the event handler that should trigger the change on the label.

Edit:  Now that you've added the code, I would suggest that you update the relevant section to try something like this.  It should prove the concept.

```
public void run() {
    ChangeAtRuntime change = new ChangeAtRuntime();
    change.setVisible(true);
    change.jLabel1.setText("New text...");
}
```

Does this code make sense?

Edit 2: Adding code for entire class.

```
public class ChangeAtRuntime extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/**
 * Creates new form ChangeAtRuntime
 */
public ChangeAtRuntime() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Name");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(151, 151, 151)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addContainerGap(204, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(116, 116, 116)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addContainerGap(162, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChangeAtRuntime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChangeAtRuntime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChangeAtRuntime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChangeAtRuntime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ChangeAtRuntime change = new ChangeAtRuntime();
            change.setVisible(true);
            change.jLabel1.setText("New text...");
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: actually si io nevver use the coding part in gui i always used netbeans drag and drop so can you help me more little pls

Comment: thanks for help sir but sorry i tried your code but its not working even after compiling the program again....

Comment: You'll need to be more specific - what does "not working" mean?  Does it not compile?  Does it throw an exception?

Comment: dear sir i change the code as you said in run method so the issue is i set the text as my name but its not changed even at runtime of the application and after compiling and executing it again

Comment: I added the full class, with my change, to my response above.  It works exactly as expected on my machine - it displays a window with a label containing "New text...".